# Reading Mapr files using TextIO

Tags: apache-beam

I am able to read Mapr Files by using TextIO.Read with the files put in hadoop folder and able to write files in hadoop folder.  But I am not sure if I need to use org.apache.beam.sdk.io.hdfs since Mapr files are based on HDFS.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't quite understand your request. You're saying you're able to read and write files using the standard TextIO - are you asking whether this is the best way to interact with HDFS from Beam or whether one needs to explicitly use something from io.hdfs? If that is your question, the answer is yes: all Beam file-based IOs transparently interact with various supported filesystems and this is the recommended way of interacting with them from Beam.

Comment: Thanks jkff, that was what i was looking. So TextIO is compatible with MaprFS files also.

Comment: Thanks, I've converted my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Beam file-based IOs transparently interact with various supported filesystems and this is the recommended way of interacting with them from Beam. There is no need to explicitly use classes from the `io.hdfs` package.